# How to write query in CouchDB for M-N relation?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have two types of documents in CouchDB: Users and Music. Each user can add the type of music  to his profile. The structure of the documents is:

```
User { uid: ... , type: 'user', name: ...., surname: ....};

Music {mid: ..., type: 'music', genre: 'rock'};

User_Music { uid: ... , mid: ....};
```

I want to make a query to join these documents... How can I do that in CouchDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can't join documents in a single query from the server as you might in a relational database.  However, you can create a view that sorts the users and their music in order, so that you have almost the equivalent result.  However all documents must have a common key field. In your example, you can only pseudo-join any two of your document types.  Here's how:

Modify your join document to include a type:

```
User_Music {umid: ..., type: 'usermusic', uid: ... , mid: ....};
```

Then the view:

```js
{
    "map":function(doc) {
        if (doc.type == 'user') {
            emit([doc._id, 0], doc);
        } else if (doc.type == 'usermusic') {
            emit([doc.uid, 1, mid], doc);
        }
    }
}
```

will return a list of music ids sorted by user_id.  You can query the view for an individual by passing a startkey and an endkey, for example, startkey "["user1"]" and endkey "["user1",{}]" to get the list of music for user1 - then iterate the results and query the music document for each music_id returned.